# How to capture Open3d screen without saving

Tags: opencv, image-processing, open3d

I want to use the open3d image screen right away without saving it as a file.

However, the 'capture_screen_image' function provided by open3d must save the image.
(http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.visualization.Visualizer.html)

This causes the problem of having to read the saved image back to 'cv2.imread'.

I wonder if there are other ways to solve this problem or other functions provided by open3d.

Comment: What kind of rendering backend is used in Open3D? Maybe you can find a way to read the used frame buffer after rendering, or to specify a buffer where the image is rendered to. Your OS probably also provides a way (a function call) to read/capture the actual screen/window to user memory, but it might be hard to synchronize that with the rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`capture_screen_float_buffer()`](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.visualization.Visualizer.html#open3d.visualization.Visualizer.capture_screen_float_buffer) instead of `capture_screen_image()`.

Remember the result is a (normalised) float numpy mat, not a typical `np.uint8` typed one so depending on the use, you might also need to scale it back up to 0-255 range and cast as `np.uint8`:

```py
# get the image
o3d_screenshot_mat = visualizer.capture_screen_float_buffer()
# scale and convert to uint8 type
o3d_screenshot_mat = (255.0 * np.asarray(o3d_screenshot_mat)).astype(np.uint8)
# use as required
# cv2.imshow("screenshot", o3d_screenshot_mat) , PIL.Image.fromarray(o3d_screenshot_mat , "RGB"), etc.
```

(e.g. if you want to visualise, remap to 0-255 range, otherwise leave data as is and simply save/load as needed)

Comment: Above solution worked for me after passing do_render=True to capture_screen_float_buffer